# WSL clipboard win32yank in init.lua

Tags: lua, neovim

I just installed neovim in its latest version and I have a problem with the configuration, I want to do the following:

```
let g:clipboard = {
      \   'name': 'win32yank-wsl',
      \   'copy': {
      \      '+': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
      \      '*': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
      \    },
      \   'paste': {
      \      '+': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
      \      '*': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
      \   },
      \   'cache_enabled': 0,
      \ }
```

which works with an init.vim, however in my init.lua not, I looked for solutions to this and discovered that I should use at the beginning:

```
vim.g.clipboard
```

in doing so I wanted to put the rest in the same way as before:

```
vim.g.clipboard = {
      \   'name': 'win32yank-wsl',
      \   'copy': {
      \      '+': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
      \      '*': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
      \    },
      \   'paste': {
      \      '+': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
      \      '*': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
      \   },
      \   'cache_enabled': 0,
      \ }
```

And I got the following error:

```
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim.lua:63: /home/us/.config/nvim/lua/basic-settings.lua:14:
 unexpected symbol near '\'
```

so I decided to remove the **/** :

```
vim.g.clipboard = {
         'name': 'win32yank-wsl',
         'copy': {
            '+': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
            '*': 'win32yank.exe -i --crlf',
          },
         'paste': {
            '+': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
            '*': 'win32yank.exe -o --lf',
         },
         'cache_enabled': 0,
       }
```

and I got the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/us/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim.lua:63: /home/us/.config/nvim/lua/basic-settings.lua:14:
 '}' expected (to close '{' at line 13) near ':'
```

**How can I solve this? Despite searching I can't find another alternative**

Comment: Lua tables use equal signs instead of colons.

Comment: I just changed it, and it gives me the following error:  '}' expected (to
close '{' at line 13) near '=' @luther

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
vim.g.clipboard = {
  name = "win32yank-wsl",
  copy = {
    ["+"] = "win32yank.exe -i --crlf",
    ["*"] = "win32yank.exe -i --crlf"
  },
  paste = {
    ["+"] = "win32yank.exe -o --crlf",
    ["*"] = "win32yank.exe -o --crlf"
  },
  cache_enable = 0,
}
```